# Karkops,M vs Dautov R. Is this a win really?

Tags: analysis, rook-endgame

Karsten Müller analyses this position as win for black.

```
8/R4p2/6p1/4k2p/p6P/r5P1/5PK1/8 b - - 0 44
```

He thinks 44.. Kd5! is the only move to win.  I tried to follow his suggestions whilst playing against Shredder to no avail.

1...Kd5 2.Kf1  Kc5 3.Ke2  Ra2+ 4.Kf3 f5 5.Ke3 Kb4 6.Rb7+  Kc3 7.Rc7+  Kb3 8.Rb7+ Kc2 9.Rc7+  Kd1 10.Rd7+ Ke1 11.f3  Rb2 12.Kf4 a3 13.Ra7 Rb3 14.g4  Rb4+ 15.Kg5 hxg4 16.Rxa3  g3 17.Ra2  Kf1 18.Kxg6

```
8/8/6K1/5p2/1r5P/5Pp1/R7/5k2 b - - 0 18
```

18..g2 19.Kxf5 g1=Q 20.Ra1+ Kg2 21.Rxg1+  Kxg1 22.h5  Kf2 23.h6 Rh4 24.Kg6  Kxf3 25.Kg7 Kf4 26.h7 Rg4+ 27.Kh8 Kf5

Is he wrong in stating this? Is his theory outdated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind it looks like the correct continuation is

18.. f4 19.Kf5 g2

```
8/8/8/5K1P/1r3p2/5P2/R5p1/5k2 b - - 4 20
```

20.h5 g1=Q 21.Ra1+ Kg2 22.Rxg1+ Kxg1 23.h6 Kf2 24.h7 Rb8 25.Kxf4 Rh8 26.Kg5 Rxh7 27.f4 Rg7+ 28.Kf6 Rg4 29.f5 Kf3 30.Ke7 Re4+ 31.Kd6 Rf4 32.Ke6 Kg4 33.f6 Kg5 34.f7 Kg6 35.f8=N+ Rxf8 36.Ke5 Rf6 37.Ke4 Rf5 38.Ke3 Kg5 39.Ke4 Kg4 40.Ke3 Rf4 41.Ke2 Rf3 42.Kd2 Kf4 43.Kc2 Re3 44.Kd1 Kf3 45.Kd2 Kf2 46.Kd1 Re2 47.Kc1 Ke3 48.Kb1 Kd3 49.Kc1 Rh2 50.Kb1 Kc3 51.Ka1 Kb3 52.Kb1 Rh1#

Comment: Great self contained Q&A!  +2